# get random string with limit 10 maximum ios?

Tags: iphone

am generating random string it contains alpha numberic values. The thing is i need to set exactly 10 digits to store in a particular string sometime i getting 10 digits exactly but most of the time i am getting 4,5,7, or even 1 character values :

here my sample code :

```
 NSString *alphabet  = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY0123456789";
 NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:10];
 for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
    unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
    [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
    NSLog(@"%@",s);
}
```

my nslog : 
    y

yC

yCD

yCDC

yCDCd

yCDCdP

yCDCdP1

yCDCdP1F

yCDCdP1Fg

yCDCdP1Fgq

Comment: Not sure what are you asking for. But try writing that NSLog after for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code.

Just, put `NSLog(@"%@",s);` right out of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have put your `NSLog` inside the `for` loop. That might make you think it's wrong. Take

```
NSLog(@"%@",s);
```

out of the loop.